How to Move Checklists Between Trello Cards?
I wish to move my Checklist C from Card A to Card B.
C has some checked and some unchecked items, and I wish to maintain their status after the move.
How can I achieve that?
Note: I am aware of a 'Copy items from' option when instantiating a new Checklist, but using that resets the checked/unchecked status of all items in C, forcing me to manually check all reset items one-by-one.
